# SQL Update table error : DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dbcc

```
update Calls 
set 
Call_Closed = GETDATE()
where CallId = 4266576;
```

I have a table named calls. Whenever i'm trying to update any column in this table it throws an  error. I have logged in with "sa" account in the server and it is the admin account. The above column datetype is a datetime. Also,updating any column in the table is throwing the below error.
 
 
**Error Details**

```
*String or binary data would be truncated.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
The statement has been terminated.*
```

**Trigger on the table**

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgrMonitorDoneWho ON Calls
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS  
begin   

    DECLARE @ExecStr varchar(50), @Qry nvarchar(255)

    CREATE TABLE #inputbuffer 
    (
      EventType nvarchar(30), 
      Parameters int, 
      EventInfo nvarchar(255)
    )

    SET @ExecStr = 'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(' + STR(@@SPID) + ')'

    INSERT INTO #inputbuffer 
    EXEC (@ExecStr)

    SET @Qry = (SELECT EventInfo FROM #inputbuffer)


    INSERT INTO tblDoneWhoMonitor(CallId,DoneWho,Operation,Query)
    SELECT  case
            when inserted.CallId is null then deleted.CallId
            when deleted.CallId is null then inserted.CallId
            else deleted.CallId end,
            case
            when inserted.CallId is null then deleted.DoneWho
            when deleted.CallId is null then inserted.DoneWho
            else deleted.DoneWho end, 
            case
            when inserted.CallId is null then 'DELETE'
            when deleted.CallId is null then 'INSERT'
            else  'UPDATE' end,
            @Qry
    FROM inserted
    FULL OUTER JOIN deleted
    ON inserted.CallId = deleted.CallId
end
```

Comment: what's the data type of `Call_Closed`

Comment: Datetime, it gives error on every column if i try to update. Nothing related to column type

Comment: Please add to your question the table definition for `Calls`.

Comment: And what about data type of `CallId`? you could try `where CallId = '4266576'`

Comment: Is there any trigger on this table that gets fired that would cause this?

Comment: Callid is int. Nothing related to that select query runs perfectly

Comment: there is one tigger on the table

Comment: Can you post the trigger?

Comment: i have edited the question and posted the trigger details. You can check it from there.

Comment: This is the statement it is getting the error from: INSERT INTO #inputbuffer 
    EXEC (@ExecStr). Change the EventInfo column to nvarchar(max) and it will work. There isn't enough room in the 255.

Comment: Can you provide more details on this and the solution?

Comment: Data is daily inserted and updated in the calls table from the front end application. But now i was updating the table from sql then it threw the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EventInfo column is too small. Change it to max. You will need to change the @Qry to nvarchar(max) as well.

```
CREATE TABLE #inputbuffer 
    (
      EventType nvarchar(30), 
      Parameters int, 
      EventInfo nvarchar(max)
    )

@Qry nvarchar(max)
```

And in turn you will need to modify the table definition for tblDoneWhoMonitor to accept the Query as well.